# Unity 2019.3.0f1 one sided meshes with baked lightmap dark

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using unity 2019.3.0f1, with HDRP. I have made a simple room mesh, that has only one sided walls, facing inwards. Turning the room static, having it generate lightmap uv, and setting the light static makes it completely black, when scene lightning is used. I've attached some images. I tried turning backface tolerance to 0, but it did not help.

[Without lights (scene lightning not used)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k88zU.png)

[With lights (scene lightning used).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfBLy.png)

Any help is appreciated :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my original answer was untrue, unfortunately. Turns out, when I created the mask, I've set green to 0, setting ambient occlusion to 0. Because of this, it handled everything occluded (from ambience). Setting ambient occlusion to 1 manually (and adding full green on every mask afterwards) fixes the issue.